# Golang GORM and several tables associations

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

Structs:

```
type (
  User struct{
    ID int64
    Name string
  }
  Group struct{
    ID int64
    Name string
    Users []User
  }
)
```

I Insert width:

```
users := []User{}
user := User{ID: int64(1)}
gormConn.First(&user) // .Error is nil, user with ID=1 exists
users = append(users, user)

group := Group{
  Name: "Grrr",
  Users: users,
}
gormConn.Create(&group)
```

But when I call `gormConn.Find(&groups)`, I will get `[{id: 1, name: "Grrr", users: null}]` instead of `[{id: 1, name: "Grrr", users: [{id:1, name: "Usr"}]}]`

Also in SQL table `groups` column `users` not found.
(all structs will `gormConn.AutoMigrate`)

Answer (score 1):

Loading the foreign key related tables using ORM is called as **Eager Loading**. EagerLoading is off by default in GORM by using `Find()`. Better use `Preload()` for loading the nested data.

Link for official documentation - http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#preloading-eager-loading